# Bind a VueX store state value to an input (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm new with VueJS, and I'm creating a VueJS app where you can get some informations about a Github User,
(example: https://api.github.com/users/versifiction)

I created a store with VueX, but I need to update the value written by the user in the input,
My "inputValue" is always at "" (its default value) and when I type inside the input, the store value still at ""

I tried this :
Input.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="input">
    <input
      type="text"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      v-model="inputValue"
      @change="setInputValue(inputValue)"
      @keyup.enter="getResult(inputValue)"
    />
    <input type="submit" @click="getResult(inputValue)" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import store from "../store";

export default {
  name: "Input",
  props: {
    placeholder: String,
  },
  computed: {
    inputValue: () => store.state.inputValue,
  },
  methods: {
    setInputValue: (payload) => {
      store.commit("setInputValue", payload);
    }
  },
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped></style>
```

and this :
store/index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    inputValue: "",
  },
  getters: {
    getInputValue(state) {
      return state.inputValue;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setInputValue(state, payload) {
      console.log("setInputValue");
      console.log("payload ", payload);
      state.inputValue = payload;
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the vuex docs in the [`form handling`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#form-handling) section you should do :

```
  :value="inputValue"
      @change="setInputValue"
```

and

```
 methods: {
    setInputValue: (event) => {
      store.commit("setInputValue", event.target.value);
    }
  }
```

Comment: A more elegant solution would be to use https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields

Comment: @Komninos thanks for the suggestion, this module is useful when we have many fields bound to vuex state

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and elegant way to bind vuex and a component would be to use computed properties.
The above code would become,

```
 <input
      type="text"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      v-model="inputValue"
      @keyup.enter="getResult(inputValue)"
    />
```

and inside your computed properties, you'll need to replace inputValue with following code.

```
computed: {
    inputValue: {
      set(val){
        this.$store.commit(‘mutationName’, val)
      },
      get() {
        return this.$store.stateName
      }
    }
}
```