# How can I store the value of each input into vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, v-for, v-model

This is my "Test.vue"components

```
    <template>
    <div>
      <div>
          <button  @click="decrenumber (id)">-</button>
          <input name="test" type="text" :key="id" v-model.number="num">
          <label for="test" ></label>
          <button @click="increnumber (id)">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    import { mapState } from 'vuex';
    
    export default {
      name: 'Test',
      data() {
        return {
          num: 0,
        };
      },
      props: {
        id: { type: Number, default: 0 },
      },
      methods: {
        increnumber(id) {
          this.num += 1;
          this.$emit('update', this.num);
        },
        decrenumber(id) {
          this.num -= 1;
          this.$emit('update', this.num);
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

`And I have 5 Test.vue components in my TestView.vue`

```
    <template>
        <div >
           <Test :id="index" v-for="(n,index) in 5" @update="selfUpdate"></Test>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    
    import Test from '../components/Test.vue';
    
    export default {
      name: 'TestView',
      components: {
        Test,
      },
      data() {
        return {
          inputValue: 0,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        selfUpdate(num) {
          this.inputValue = num;
          this.$store.state.test.number = this.inputValue;
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

How can I store the value of each input from TestView.vue into vuex?
I know it is possible to use array.push() but this keeps increasing
How did I just make the input only exist in five indexes,
If you enter the input in the same field, it can replace the old value

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61955900/bind-a-vuex-store-state-value-to-an-input-vuejs

Comment: You don't set the value on state, you need to create a mutation that set the value for you, and call `commit` with the payload to update the state. For more info refer to https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html

Comment: @LuisBrito I know how to call commit and create mutation to set the value, my quetion is i don't know how to store each 5 input's value, and when change same input value how can i overwrite old value.

Answer (score 1):

To save the value of each input you'll need a key pair of input/value for each input, this way when updating a value you will know which one to update.

I adjusted the component to save each value;

The first change is on the template, it calls the method `selfUpdate` and passes the value emitted by the component as well the input index, so the `inputValues` will be updated only for that specific input.

The second adjustment is on an assignment of the value, it's assigned to a position that refers to the input, that's why the `index` is passed along with the value.

```
<template>
  <div >
    <Test
        :id="index"
        v-for="(n,index) in 5"
        @update="(num) => selfUpdate(num, index)"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script>

import Test from '../components/Test.vue';

export default {
  name: 'TestView',
  components: {
    Test,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      inputValues: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    selfUpdate(num, index) {
      this.inputValue[index] = num; // saves the value at index `index`
      this.$store.state.test.number = this.inputValue;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am new to vue  and I am not familiar with some of the usage.
Through your answer I found that I am missing the use of input index Thank you very much for your answer.